# How do I get the browser to download the updated JS file in a Laravel app

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a Laravel app and made updates to a JavaScript file. As I test the updates, I notice that it was not working. I opened the browser (Google Chrome) Developer Tools and checked the JavaScript file (under Sources). I noticed that it still has the old code.

Is there any cached file being created that I need to update as well?

I'm using Laravel ver 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the local cache from your browser. You can fix this by adding a version number or hash to the url of your javascript file.

For example:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Becomes:

```
<script src="/js/app.js?1234"></script>
```

This way your browser will see the file as a new resource and not use the existing cache.

Comment: It worked. This solved my problem. Thank you very much :-)